# throwing "Unsupported Media Type" for rest end point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Team,

i am facing "unsupported media type" issue, while invoking the below end point in spring boot application. And Template class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`

````
   @RequestMapping(value = "/template", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON},
            headers={"Accept=application/json"})
   public ResponseEntity<Response> create ( @RequestPart("file") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file,
                                                      @RequestPart("templatedata") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank Template template)```
````

Comment: how do you call the endpoint?

Comment: it's related to request field that you are trying. please check those and change your code.